# How do you get the IP address of a server (not a webserver) but a TCP server created on a wifi module in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tcpclient

I need to get the IP address of a Wi-Fi module, running a TCP server. The application will open the WiFi connections settings page to allow the user to connect to the Wi-Fi module's created network (requiring the password to be entered)- **see attached picture**. The server (Wi-FI module) IP address is 172.1.4.155 (for example) but when I try to get the IP address in Xamarin.Forms using ***GetLocalIPAddress()*** (attached below), the address it returns is the local IP address of the device (Phone)- 172.1.4.55 (for example). I need to be able to get the IP address programmatically without a user input in an Application.

[image: Example of the WiFi connection Settings page]

Is there any way to get the IP address of the (external) non-device specific IP address? I assume the returned IP address of the phone is the DHCP assigned IP address. I need to get the server IP address as it is essential to establish a TCP socket connection between the phone and the WiFi module. I have been trying to look for a solution without any success for a few days now so any help/suggestions or examples will be greatly appreciated.

The code below is the **GetLocalIPAddress()** function to get the IP address.

```
    public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
            //return "";
        }
        //throw new Exception("Local IP Address Not Found!");
        return "None";
    }
```

Comment: Seems to me that this is prone to races if you're assuming it's an IP address assigned by DHCP. By the time you *do something with the answer*, your lease may have expired and (for whatever reasons) a new address been assigned instead of continuing to use the old one.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, this is a very valid point. Is there any way to get around this problem or at least get the IP to try and create a socket connection with the IP before it is re-assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to Read IP Address in XAMARIN Form, i have Created the DependencyServices in both IOS and Android projects and getting a proper IP address. Below is code to get IP address.

In PCL Project

```
public interface IIPAddressManager
    {
        String GetIPAddress();
    }
```

In IOS Project

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(YourAppNamespace.iOSUnified.iOS.DependencyServices.IPAddressManager))]

namespace YourAppNamespace.iOSUnified.iOS.DependencyServices
{
    class IPAddressManager : IIPAddressManager
    {
        public string GetIPAddress()
        {
            String ipAddress = "";

            foreach (var netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 ||
                    netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
                {
                    foreach (var addrInfo in netInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                    {
                        if (addrInfo.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                            ipAddress = addrInfo.Address.ToString();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return ipAddress;
        }
    }
}
```

In Android Project.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(YourAppNamespace.Android.Android.DependencyServices.IPAddressManager))]

namespace YourAppNamespace.Android.Android.DependencyServices
{
    class IPAddressManager : IIPAddressManager
    {
        public string GetIPAddress()
        {
            IPAddress[] adresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

            if (adresses !=null && adresses[0] != null)
            {
                return adresses[0].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call a DependencyServices in UI project.

```
string ipaddress = DependencyService.Get<IIPAddressManager>().GetIPAddress
```

Comment: This method will work to get you an IP address but not for my specific need- I need to be able to get the IP address of a TCP server (not the DHCP assigned IP address of the device).