# TCP socket not working as expected in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, tcp, xamarin.forms

I have a problem connecting to a TCP server using the **rda.SocketsForPCL** NuGet plugin for Xamarin in MVS. I am trying to have a socket connection established in a for loop, as I cant find the actual server IP address as stated in my [Previous TCP Socket related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649549/how-do-you-get-the-ip-address-of-a-server-not-a-webserver-but-a-tcp-server-cre).

I have a for loop that checks all the possible IP addresses that the server could have in its DHCP address pool which is only the last byte of the IP address (254 possibilities). I then do a **client.Socket.Connected** check, which is a feature of the package. The problem with this check is that it gets a number of **false positives** (Connected status as true) although the IP address is not valid and the server does not show any connection (when I manually type the expected IP address of the server to connect to in the socket connection library- I get a connection acknowledgement; so my server is fine).

Is there a known bug with the NuGet plugin when it is used in a for loop trying to connect a socket using multiple IP addresses? Or is there a problem with my logic?

The for loop function is as follows:

```
public TcpSocketClient client;

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{   
    broken4 = i.ToString();
    SharedSocket.Instance().setSocket(1, IPads + 
    broken4);
    await Task.Delay(2);

    if (client.Socket.Connected)
    {
        string b = "Connected";
        string c = IPads + broken4;
        Console.WriteLine("IP = " + broken4);
    }
    else{}
}
```

My question essentially is, is there an alternative method to have a TCP socket being created using the rda.SocketsForPCL plugin by *trying* different IP addresses in some sort of loop? Why this above method is not working as expected and if there is an alternative? Please provide assistance if possible. Thank you in advance.